# Baking normals issue

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

I am trying to bake normals for this guitar i had made, but it never bakes properly. I have tried playing with the extrusion, ray distance, with cage, but i never get the whole thing baked, nor do they look good, as in i get greens and yellows. Sometimes, when i bake the normals, i dont get anything at all! Is there a better way to do this or am i missing something?
Thank you

I did manage to get something better by changing tangent to object in the baking settings, but it looks like this, and is transparent. Not sure if this is accecptable:

https://imgur.com/a/IGWDxTq

https://www.mediafire.com/file/xbptek0u2702nln/Fender+Esquire.blend/file

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: hello maybe share your file

Comment: I apoligze. As always, i was too eager to post. I put in my file

Comment: Apply the scale of the high and low-poly, switch to Space > Tangent instead of Object unless you have a reason why you prefer Object, in that case you'll need to select Object in the Normal Map node, put the Extrusion at a low value, like 0.001, put the Distance at 0, and it seems to work pretty well except for some small faces, but actually I'm not sure what you're trying to bake as it doesn't seem like there's any details on your high-poly?

Comment: To be honest, i was looking at how guitars are made in video games and looking at other models of guitars and saw that they all had a normal map, so i figured that it was good practice or something. If i were to remove some more vertices or  faces, would it be worth it to bake the normal map?